# How to change variable within SKAction sequence?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

When my viewDidLoad gets called, I run the following action:

```
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(chainsawDropper),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)
            ])
        ))
```

Then in my update method I decrease the "waitDuration" by 1.  The problem is that the sequence continues to run but never uses the updated "waitDuration".  How can I achieve this?

Comment: you'll have to either stop and recreate the sequence or store the wait action in an ivar so that you can change its speed property

Comment: How would I store the waitForDuration or waitDuration variable in an ivar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run the action with a tag then you can override it at any time:

```
func updateActionForDuration(duration:NSTimeInterval) {
    self.runAction(  SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(
         [SKAction.runBlock(chainsawDropper),
         SKAction.waitForDuration(duration)])), 
    withKey: "action key")
}
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem of the duration variable being changed?